# How can I limit Perl's split function?

Tags: perl, split

I have trying this:

```
$string ="Group: ALL:ALL:Good";

@str2  = split (/:/,':',2);

print "@str2";
```

I am looking in `$str[0] = Group`  and `$str[1]= ALL:ALL:Good`.

It not working. What would be issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $string = "Group: ALL:ALL:Good";
my @str    = split(/:/, $string, 2);

print $str[0];
print $str[1];
```

Comment: Downvote because this code is sloppy and causes errors when running under `strict` and `warnings` pragma. Care to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Don't you mean this?

```
@str2  = split (/:/,$string,2);
```

Otherwise, you'll be splitting the string `:`, which seems kind of pointless.

Answer (score 3):

To use limit with split

```
@array = split /PATTERN/,EXPR,LIMIT;
```

From [PerlDoc split function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> If LIMIT is specified and positive, it
>   represents the maximum number of
>   fields the EXPR will be split into,
>   though the actual number of fields
>   returned depends on the number of
>   times PATTERN matches within EXPR. If
>   LIMIT is unspecified or zero, trailing
>   null fields are stripped (which
>   potential users of pop would do well
>   to remember). If LIMIT is negative, it
>   is treated as if an arbitrarily large
>   LIMIT had been specified. Note that
>   splitting an EXPR that evaluates to
>   the empty string always returns the
>   empty list, regardless of the LIMIT
>   specified.